# Como colocar animação de "aguarde" no Android?

Tags: android, mobile, animação

Gostaria de saber como coloco uma animação de "Aguarde" enquanto faço uma tarefa pesada no Android. No caso, quando o usuário digitar o cep quero que rode uma animação pedindo para aguardar enquanto faço a requisição.

```
private Activity context;
private ProgressDialog progress;

private class BuscaCepTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Aguarde...", "Buscando CEP...", true, true);
    }

    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        StringBuilder result = null;
        int respCode = -1;

        try {
            url = new URL("http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/" + params[0] + ".json");
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            do {
                if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                    respCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                }
            } while (respCode == -1);

            if (respCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                httpURLConnection = null;
            }
        }

        return (result != null) ? result.toString() : null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);

        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
            EditText rua = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rua);
            rua.setText(object.getString("logradouro"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        progress.dismiss();
    }
}
```

.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.formulario);

    final EditText endereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endereco);
    endereco.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            BuscaCepTask buscarCep = new BuscaCepTask();
            buscarCep.execute(endereco.getText().toString());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Você quer saber como fazer a animação ou quer saber onde deve iniciar a animação?

Comment: os dois! Eu vou ter que criar uma classe?

Comment: A animação deve ser iniciada no método `onPreExecute()` e parada no `onPostExecute()`. Há muitas formas de fazer animações em Android sugiro que leia primeiro sobre o [assunto](http://blog.caelum.com.br/criando-animacoes-no-android/) e se depois tiver alguma dúvida mais concreta coloque uma questão.

Comment: Eu posso chamar o método onPreExecute() dentro do onCreate?

Comment: Você não "chama" o `onPreExecute`, ele é um método da própria `AsyncTask`, você só precisa sobrescrever dentro da sua classe e dentro do seu ciclo ele será executado primeiro. Na sua própria classe você pode utilizar o [`ProgressDialog`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) para obter uma interface indicando o *"carregando..."*.

Comment: Editei meu post. É mais ou menos assim que deveria ficar?

Comment: Teoricamente sim, para garantir, é bom colocar a anotação `@Overrride` no método `onPreExecute`. Você testou? É assim que você vai saber se vai funcionar.

Comment: Não está dando certo, quando começo a digitar o cep no formulário o app trava e para de funcionar. Alguém tem uma ideia?

Comment: Cada vez que um número é digitado você está chamando o webservice. Você precisa restringir isso para que seja feito somente quando todos os 8 dígitos forem informados.

Comment: if (endereco.toString().length() == 8) ?

Comment: Obrigado a todos que me ajudaram. Deu certo agora.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tá aí a solução em código:

```
private class uploadPhoto extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

            private ProgressDialog dialog;
        protected void onPostExecute(Void dResult) {

            dialog.cancel();

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {


        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Myactivity.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("uploading...");
        dialog.show();

            }

    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // call upload photo here.
    }

}
```

Para chamar a asyncTask use:

```
new uploadPhoto().execute();
```

Comment: Mas dessa maneira o diálogo inicia assim que a classe é chamada. Eu quero que a animação apareça somente quando for buscar o cep.

Comment: Ai é só chamar new pesquisaCep().execute(); e implementar essa animação dentro da classe de pesquisa do CEP ai sim ela inicia só quando for fazer pesquisa.

Comment: Me ajuda a implementar isso no meu código.

Comment: Claro cara, ajudo sim.

Comment: Joga no Github que te ajudo com o código, você vai ver que é bem simples, abraços.

Comment: Obrigado pela boa vontade, mas já consegui. Abraço!

Comment: Opa, vlw cara qualquer coisa estamos ai.

Comment: Editei a resposta. Se quiser debater o que te incomodou, o lugar é o [meta].

Answer (score 1):

A resposta escolhida foi a de cima, mas como deu certo irei mostrar como ficou o meu código corrigido.

```
private String caminhoArquivo;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

private class BuscaCepTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        dialog = new ProgressDialog(Formulario.this);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.setMessage("Buscando CEP...");
        dialog.show();
    }

    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        StringBuilder result = null;
        int respCode = -1;

        try {
            url = new URL("http://cep.correiocontrol.com.br/" + params[0] + ".json");
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            do {
                if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                    respCode = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();
                }
            } while (respCode == -1);

            if (respCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpURLConnection.getInputStream()));
                result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (httpURLConnection != null) {
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                httpURLConnection = null;
            }
        }

        return (result != null) ? result.toString() : null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        dialog.cancel();
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(s);
            EditText rua = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rua);
            rua.setText(object.getString("logradouro"));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.formulario);

    final EditText endereco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.endereco);
    endereco.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (endereco.length() == 8) {
                BuscaCepTask buscarCep = new BuscaCepTask();
                buscarCep.execute(endereco.getText().toString());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Opa que bom que pude ajudar de alguma forma.